# Inductive principle for mutually recursive definitions

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

I am going over Models of Computations and I have stumbled upon an excercise I have issues working out. Consider the following pair of mutually defined recursive functions:

$$
evens(w) := \epsilon\ for\ w = \epsilon\\
evens(w) :=  odds(x)\ for\ w = ax
$$

with

$$
odds(w) := \epsilon\ for\ w = \epsilon\\
odds(w) := a.evens(x)\ for\ w = ax
$$

(The dot operator is just concatenation.)

Now suppose we would like to show the following:
$$
\forall w\ x, even(|w|) \rightarrow evens(w.x) = evens(w) . evens(x) 
$$

I would naturally proceed with induction on **w**, with the empty case being rather trivial, following from the neutrality of epsilon wrt. concatenation.

However I find it somewhat awkward to find a suitable inductive hypothesis for the case where **w = ht**.
I was thinking about something along the lines of:
$$
even(|t|) \rightarrow evens(t.x) = evens(t).evens(x)
$$
But considering evens-ness is defined in terms of odds, this hypothesis seems somewhat pointless. I proceeded like so:

$$
evens(htx) = evens(ht).evens(x)\\
odds(tx) = odds(t).evens(x)
$$

Now considering **|w|** was originally even and non-empty and **w = ht**, having stripped **h** away, **|t|** is odd and as such it surely takes the shape of **t = h't'**. So we have:
$$
odds(h't'x) = odds(h't').evens(x)\\
h'.evens(t'x) = h'.evens(t').evens(x)\\
evens(t'x) = evens(t').evens(x)\
$$

I now know that **|t'|** is even so I could feed the aforementioned inductive hypothesis, but it is expressed in terms of fixed **t**, not **any w** (nor **t'** which I currently have).

I have a feeling that I also need to somehow include some information about **odds** in my inductive principle, but i have no idea how.

Comment: Try to strengthen your inductive hypothesis by showing the following: $$\forall w\ x, (even(|w|) \rightarrow evens(w.x) = evens(w) . evens(x)) \wedge (odd(|w|) \rightarrow odds(w.x) = odds(w).evens(x))$$.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas huh, this seems to hold - but I can't see myself having come up with it, ehh...

Comment: @EvangelosBampas I am still somewhat confused - what  was the reasoning process behind coming up with this solution?

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote is true but it may not be actually necessary or even helpful. Going back to your original approach, what you really want to do is induction on $|w|$. Supposing the statement holds for $w$ up to a length of $k$, consider $w$ of length $k+1$. If $k+1$ is odd, the statement holds vacuously. If $k+1$ is even, then write $w=abt$, where $|t|=k-1$ and $|t|$ is even. Now, the LHS of what you want to prove is $evens(w.x)=evens(abtx)=odds(btx)=b.evens(tx)=b.evens(t).evens(x)$ (last step: I.H.). The RHS is $evens(w).evens(x)=evens(abt).evens(x)=odds(bt).evens(x)=b.evens(t).evens(x)$.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas Oh my, the proof is entirely trivial with induction on the length of string rather than on its shape. You should post this as an answer :). (Meanwhile I am back to thinking cap about good inductive principles in general, and how they relate to mutually recursive definitions. The extra information injected into the hypothesis you had mentioned in the previous comment is definitely something  to consider - I will try to work out a proof by induction on shape of w as well.) Thanks a lot, I appreciate.

Comment: I will try to make this into a comprehensive answer. By the way, you can translate the proof by induction on |w| into a proof by structural induction that essentially repeats the same argument.

Comment: @EvangelosBampas It seems that if **k + 1 is odd** I need to use the fact that **odd(|w|) -> odds(w.x) = odds(w) . evens(x)**, which I am guessing *should* be fine considering the length is strictly less as **evens** strips one symbol away. (What's your reasoning behind saying it holds vacuously forthe odd case, am I missing something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me restate what we want to prove:
$$\forall x\,\forall w \ \text{if $|w|$ is even, then } evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$$

For this, we fix an arbitrary $x$ and we prove the following by induction:
$$\forall w \ \text{if $|w|$ is even, then } evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$$

Now, one way to prove this is by induction on $|w|$:

> If $|w|=0$, then $w=\epsilon$ and $|w|$ is even, so we must prove that $evens(\epsilon.x)=evens(\epsilon).evens(x)$. This is true because $evens(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ by definition.
>
> Supposing the statement holds for $w$ up to a length of $k\geq 0$, consider a string $w$ of length $k+1$. We must show that
>   $$\text{if $k+1$ is even, then } evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$$
>   We distinguish two cases: $k+1$ is either odd or even.
>
> If $k+1$ is odd, then the premise of the implication that we need to show is false. Therefore, the implication is true.
>
> If $k+1$ is even, we need to show that $evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$. We write $w=a.b.t$, where $a,b$ are symbols and $|t|=k-1$. (We know we can do this because $k+1$ is even and $k+1\geq 1$, therefore $|w|=k+1\geq 2$.) By the definitions of the functions $evens$ and $odds$, we have:
>   $$evens(w.x)=evens(a.b.t.x)=odds(b.t.x)=b.evens(t.x)$$
>   But $|t|\leq k$, so we can use the inductive hypothesis to conclude that
>   $$evens(w.x)=b.evens(t.x)=b.evens(t).evens(x)$$
>   On the other hand, by the definitions of the functions $evens$ and $odds$:
>   $$evens(w).evens(x)=evens(a.b.t).evens(x)=odds(b.t).evens(x)=b.evens(t).evens(x)$$
>   Therefore, $evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$.

Since the OP was apparently going for a proof by induction on the *structure* of $w$ (i.e., assuming the statement holds for $t$, prove that it holds for $a.t$ where $a$ is a symbol), I'm including a proof along those lines. Unfortunately, in this case, the inductive hypothesis is not strong enough to allow us to conclude the proof. In cases like this, a standard technique is to *strengthen the inductive hypothesis*: we aim to prove a stronger statement than the one we originally wanted to prove, so that we can use a stronger inductive hypothesis during the proof. We will prove that
$$\begin{align}
\forall w\  & \text{if $|w|$ is even, then } evens(w.x) = evens(w) . evens(x) \  \wedge \\
 & \text{if $|w|$ is odd, then } odds(w.x) = odds(w).evens(x)  
\end{align}$$

> If $w=\epsilon$, then $|w|=0$ is even, so we must prove that $evens(\epsilon.x)=evens(\epsilon).evens(x)$. This is true because $evens(\epsilon)=\epsilon$ by definition.
>
> Supposing the statement holds for $t$, consider a string $w=a.t$, where $a$ is a symbol. We distinguish two cases: $|w|$ is either odd or even.
>
> If $|w|$ is odd, then it suffices to show that $odds(w.x) = odds(w).evens(x)$. But $odds(w.x) = odds(a.t.x) = a.evens(t.x)$, and $|t|$ is even. Therefore, from the inductive hypothesis we obtain $evens(t.x)=evens(t).evens(x)$. We conclude that $odds(w.x)=a.evens(t).evens(x)$. On the other hand, $odds(w).evens(x)=odds(a.t).evens(x)=a.evens(t).evens(x)$, which proves the claim.
>
> If $|w|$ is even, then it suffices to show that $evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$. But $evens(w.x)=evens(a.t.x)=odds(t.x)$, and $|t|$ is odd. Therefore, from the inductive hypothesis we obtain $odds(t.x)=odds(t).evens(x)$. We conclude that $evens(w.x)=odds(t).evens(x)$. On the other hand, $evens(w).evens(x)=evens(a.t).evens(x)=odds(t).evens(x)$, which proves the claim.

How does one guess the strengthened statement? It's a matter of understanding what the functions actually do. Here, $evens(w)$ just returns a string consisting of the symbols at even positions in $w$ (position numbering starts from $1$). Similarly, $odds(w)$ just returns a string consisting of the symbols at odd positions.

With this knowledge, it's actually not very surprising that $evens(w.x)=evens(w).evens(x)$ if $|w|$ is even: Sure, in order to write down the symbols at even positions of $w.x$, all you have to do is write down the symbols at even positions of $w$, all the way up to the *last* symbol of $w$ (which is at an even position because |w| is even), followed by the symbols at even positions of $x$.

Now, when you do the structural induction, you will have to deal with a string $t$ of odd length, so you need a similar property for odd-length strings. By a similar reasoning as in the previous paragraph, this property is $odds(w.x)=odds(w).evens(x)$.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I think my approach to writing proofs is now less mechanical (wrt. just attempting to find "some" rewrites). Awesome.